# validation of tkinter entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an entry field in my tkinter GUI app. entry should only accept numbers including decimal points. I used a function to validate the entry. The problem is, it is not accepting decimal point(.) if there is a digit in front of it. (example 25.3 wont accept). if there is a point in the beginning, it is not accepting any number after that. Could anyone help me with this problem. and any suggestion to limit the maximum value in the entry field to 1000?

```
import tkinter as tk

def acceptNumber(inp):
    if inp.isdigit():
        return True
    elif inp is "":
        return True
    elif inp is ".":
        return True
    else:
        return False
win = tk.Tk()
reg = win.register(acceptNumber)

entryHere =tk.Entry(win)
entryHere.place(x=400, y=200)

entryHere.config(validate="key", validatecommand =(reg, '%P'))
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This accepts valid decimal numbers not greater than 1000:

```
def acceptNumber(inp):
    try:
        return True if inp == '' else float(inp) <= 1000
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: backspace won't work in this case to remove all digits. for example, if I typed 456, i wanna change into 786, backspace will remove only last two digits from 456 (ie. 4 will alwas be there)

Comment: if we can erase the data (using backspace in keyboard) , this is a good solution.

Comment: @sunny_old_days see updated version

Comment: Just rephrased it to look a bit nicer.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s='1234'
>>> s.isdigit()
True
>>> sdot = '1234.'
>>> sdot.isdigit()
False
```

Isn't this your problem. isdigit() means digits only.

Comment: I used two elif statements as well !